# Integral function

Tags: integration

This exercise asks me to calculate the integral function with starting point $x=0$ of the following function:
\begin{equation}
y=
\begin{cases}
2\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x<0\\
x+2\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0\leq x\leq 2\\
4\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x>2\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Is my solution correct?
I wrote:
\begin{equation}
F(x)=
\begin{cases}
\int_0 ^x 2 dt\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x<0\\
\int_0 ^x (t+2) dt\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0\leq x\leq 2\\
\int_2 ^x 4 dt\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x>2\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third part is wrong, and the whole is incomplete: you should evaluate the integrals. Thus, for example, for $x<0$ you should have

$$F(x)=\int_0^x2\,dt=[2t]_0^x=2x\;.$$

Your third part, $\int_2^x4\,dt$, is wrong because you’re supposed to be integrating from $0$, not from $2$. Thus, it should be

$$\int_0^2(t+2)dt+\int_2^x4\,dt\;;$$

I’ll leave it to you to finish evaluating that and the middle part.